# ethers is not defined

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

In hardhat, I want to access a contract outside my project in my tests.

In my `hardhat.config.js` I am able to reference external contracts no problem with an ABI and a contract address, like so:

```
const tkn1 = new ethers.Contract(ADDRESS, ABI, signer)
```

However, in my test files, I am getting `ethers is not defined` when trying to do the same thing. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have been having the same issue. First make sure your hardhat.config.js file has this line:
`require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");`

I fixed it by adding this to the top of the test file:

`const { ethers } = require("hardhat");`

But before you try that, see if your tests still run as expected. Someone told me its a linting error which made sense because my tests still ran and passed even though ethers was not defined. If this is the case, we will have to configure the linter to accept ethers as a variable. Still looking into all of it.

Comment: This is the one. A little unintuitive but works all the best.

Comment: Please check the tip in this section. https://hardhat.org/getting-started/#quick-start

Comment: Sorry for the bump, but when I add these lines to my React app, I get many more errors about `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in XXXXXXX `. My full post is [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/147555/ethers-is-not-defined-no-undef). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. I didn't know I had to install `ethers` besides `hardhat-ethers`. So I installed `ethers` by running the following command:

```
npm install --save-dev ethers
```

And added the following line to the top of the test file:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
```

It works well now.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern is **recommended in the official hardhat documentation** and it has always solved this issue for me.
Install @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox with;
`npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox`

Then add it to your `hardhat.config.js` like so;

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, ensure that `hardhat.config.js` is included in your `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue.
My solution was to move from windows to WSL2 ubuntu.