# 'ethers' is not defined no-undef

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, react

I am making a very basic React app, and I'm following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/scrappy-squirrels/tutorial-building-a-web3-frontend-with-react-e0a87ea3bad). Ethers has been updated since, however. Here is my code for App.js:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserProvider } from 'ethers';
import './App.css';
import contract from './Contracts/NFTCollectible.json';
const contractAddress = "0x6E665b48BFaeE66d5183f029C82A8c23D66bC7ce";
const abi = contract.abi;
function App() {
const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState(null);
const [provider, setProvider] = useState();
  
  
  const checkWalletIsConnected = async () => {
const { ethereum } = window;


if(!ethereum){
    console.log("A wallet is needed.")
    return;
}
else{
    console.log("Yay! You're all set up!")
}

const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts'});

if(accounts.length !== 0){
    const account = accounts[0];
    console.log("Found an authroized account:", account);
    setCurrentAccount(account); 
}else{
    console.log("No authorised account found!");
}
      }

  const connectWalletHandler = async () => { 
  const { ethereum } = window;
  
  if(!ethereum)
  {
      alert("Please install Metamask!");
  }
  try {
      
      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
      console.log("Found an account! Address: ", accounts[0]);
      setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
     } catch(err){
         console.log(err)
     }
  
  }

  const mintNftHandler = async () => { 
  try {
      const { ethereum } = window;
      
      if (ethereum){
          const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
          const signer = provider.getSigner();
          const nftContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
          
          console.log("Initialize payment!");
          let nftTxn = await nftContract.mintNFTs(1, { value: ethers.parseEther("0.01") });
          
          console.log("Mining... please wait!");
          await nftTxn.wait();
          
          console.log(`Mined, see transaction https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/${nftTxn.hash}`);
          
      }else{
          console.log("Ethereum object doesn't exist.");
      }
      
      
      
    
      
      
      
      
      
  }
  catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }
  
  
  
  
  
  
  }

  const connectWalletButton = () => {
    return (
      <button onClick={connectWalletHandler} className='cta-button connect-wallet-button'>
        Connect Wallet
      </button>
    )
  }

  const mintNftButton = () => {
    return (
      <button onClick={mintNftHandler} className='cta-button mint-nft-button'>
        Mint BoredBits NFT
      </button>
    )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    checkWalletIsConnected();
    const browserProvider = new BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
    setProvider(browserProvider);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='main-app'>
      <h1>Bored Bits</h1>
      <div>
        {currentAccount ? mintNftButton() : connectWalletButton()}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

My full error:

```
  Line 60:26:  'ethers' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 62:29:  'ethers' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 65:57:  'ethers' is not defined  no-undef
```

I have read on other similar posts that putting `const { ethers } = require("hardhat");` will resolve the error, but for me I just get hundreds of errors. The first error is: `Cannot find module 'path'`, and the rest are: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in XXXXXXX` Thanks for any help! I'm using `ethers`, `hardhat`, and `webpack`.

Answer (score 0):

import ethers as follows,

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
```